# Ball jerky motion issue in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a snooker game project using unity3d. I have a serious issue with ball movement. After applying force at cueball in a certain direction it is doing a kind of jerky movement. My camera position is fixed from top view.I have applied bouncy physics material to my cue ball. Please suggest me what exactly I have missed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CueBall1 : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform cueStick;

    private float force = 1000;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        gameObject.rigidbody.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic; 
        rigidbody.interpolation = RigidbodyInterpolation.Interpolate;

    }

    void FixedUpdate () {

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){

            rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(cueStick.forward * force,transform.position,ForceMode.Acceleration);

        }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you share a video of some sort to show what exactly is going on?

Comment: One thing is that you probably want to use ForceMode.VelocityChange instead of Acceleration. The force in your code is applied instantaneously, where as Acceleration is intended to be applied over a period of time. I imagine this to be why your force variable is set so high.

Comment: also go into Edit->Project Settings->Physics and try to set your solver iteration count higher

Comment: Hi Rowan I have tried through increasing  Solver iteration counter. But still same issue. unfortunately I can't change the force mode ForceMode.Acceleration to ForceMode.VelocityChange because it will affect my spin functionality.